# empty angular application has some ad links in the source code

Tags: angularjs

I've started to learn angular and I've just followed some tutorials. I've created my application using the command:

```
ng new my-first-app
```

and then I've started it using:

```
ng serve
```

After my application started, I've looked in the source code and I've saw this:

[image: application html code]

I've scanned my system with a commercial antivirus, but didn't found any threat.

Should I be worried?

Comment: what tutorials?

Comment: the tutorial is from the udemy. but these commands are used to create a new "empty" angular application

Comment: Why are there two arguments following the "ng new"? "my first" and "app"... or is that just a typo?

Comment: is a typo, sorry. I will edit

Comment: No problem. Yeah, looks weird. Sorry, I don't have any great advice for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ad-blocking browser extension which is injecting this CSS stylesheet into pages you view. (To be clear, this stylesheet is used to *block* ads, not to display them.)

This is harmless, and only affects you -- it won't affect others users viewing your site. If it's still bothering you, though, you can disable the extension for this site, or switch to an ad blocker which doesn't use this method. For example, one good option is [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm).

Comment: you were right. After I've disabled the ad-blocker, I'm not seeing this anymore. Thanks